# Implementing "Back button" on jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, back-button, browser-history

I'm trying to implement back button on this full ajax website.. I tried jquery history plugin but I'm sure I messed something, as the hash appears OK but the back button won't load the original content back..

This is what my menu looks like:

```
       <div id="nav" class="ajaxload menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.aspx">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And the ajax calls:

```
     $(function() {
            var $content = $('#content');
            $('.ajaxload li a').click(function() {

                $content.html('<div id="loader"></div>');

                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $content.hide().html(data).fadeIn("slow", function() { $("#loader").fadeOut("fast") });
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you were using the history plugin you may not have initialized it. When you initialize it, you pass it a callback that handles the hash changes so you can load the content again. So, for example, rather than doing something like this:

```
$('a').click(function clickedLink() {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $.history.load(href);
    doSomeAJAXRequest(href);
    return false;
});
```

You'd have to do something like this:

```
$.history.init(function hashChanged(hash) {
    doSomeAJAXRequest(href);
});
$('a').click(function clickedLink() {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $.history.load(href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this code can work with what I have? I can't seem to make it work either.. (the ajax calls won't work)

Comment: @Vitor: I don't see why it wouldn't. What code are you using?

Comment: How should my menu look like? Do I have to put the #hash? Or this is work fro the plugin?

Comment: @Vitor: The plugin should do it. Putting the hashes in the menu would work too, but then search engines wouldn't understand it.