# Implementation of History.js

Tags: html, ajax, history.js

I am trying to implement History.js for my ajax site so that I can use forward and back buttons and even bookmarks. However the example @ https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/ has me a bit confused as into how to implement it. Does anyone have a simple tutorial or example on how to use this. An example we can use to start the example is a navigation link such as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() 
{
function1();
};
```

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:function1()">Function1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:function2('param', 'param')"</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See a possible answer and related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278822/is-this-a-proper-way-to-use-history-js

Answer (score 36):

I had trouble fully understanding how to use History.js. Here is some code from their wiki with my comments for explanation:

**1. Get a reference to the history.js object**

To get a reference to the History.js object reference window.History (Capitol 'H').

```
var History = window.History;
```

To check if HTML5 history is enabled check History.enabled. History.js will still work using hash tags if it is not.

```
History.enabled
```

**2. Listen for history changes and update your view from here**

To listen for history state changes bind to the statechange event of the Adapter object.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    var State = History.getState(); 
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

**3. Manipulate history states by using push or replace**

To add a state to the history, call pushState. This will add a state to the end of the history stack which will trigger the 'statechange' event as shown above.

```
History.pushState({data:"any kind of data object"}, "State Title", "?urlforthestate=1");
```

To replace a state to the history, call replaceState. This will replace the last state in the history stack which will trigger the 'statechange' event as shown above.

```
History.replaceState({data:"any kind of data object"}, "State Title", "?urlforthestate=1");
```

The difference between pushState and replaceState is that pushState will add a state to the history list, replaceState will overwrite the last state.

NOTE: pushState and replaceState serialize the data object, so use minimal data there.

**4. If you want to add additional ui for the user to be able to navigate the history, use the navigation commands**

Use back and go to navigate the history via code.

```
History.back();
History.go(2);
```

**Additional: Using "a" tags with history**

To use "a" tags with history you will need to intercept click events and prevent the browser from navigating by using the event.preventDefault() method.

Example:

```
<a href="dogs/cats" title="Dogs and cats">Dogs and Cats</a>

$('a')​.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    History.pushState({data:title}, title, url);
})​;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am also struggling with this as an example.  I get what is shown above, but there is a lot that is missing compared to the previous history.js that used the # method.  I was able to get previous # based examples working by binding to clickable items such as an anchor in a nav menu.  This would then call a handler based on the href where the ajax call could be made. I do not see how the click events for each url get bound to here.  Everything I have tried does not intercept the url click events.

Comment: What you need to do is intercept the clicks on those hrefs and go from there. Example: ​$('a')​.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); })​. After the e.preventDefault() you can take the value of the href attribute and use it to push history states without navigating away from the page.

Comment: Thanks, I did something like that and added it above but I am not sure if it is really the proper way.  Also, I don't see why e.preventDefault() is needed.  It seems that return false; does the same thing.

Comment: The difference between using the hash tags and not using them is that the browser will not naturally refresh when the href is a hash. If you are using only the hash style then you can just let the browser take care of changing the url for you.

Comment: How will I load the contents of the URL in the pushState

Comment: Can you add an addendum on `popstate` just to have a comprehensive review?

Answer (score 3):

Refer this question: [Implementing "Back button" on jquery ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288003/implementing-back-button-on-jquery-ajax-calls)

Some more info related to [RSH](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/downloads/list)

[How to implement RSH (Really Simple History) for Ajax History Back Button](http://www.nerdswithlives.com/2008/12/ajax-history-back-rsh-really-simple.html)

Comment: ok the tutorial helped alot just one question concerning it in jquery is $('#').load() the equivalent of an ajax request such as onlick='javascript:function1();' ?